# Is it permissible to locate the abscissa of extreme points of $y=f(x)$ by powering the function first for the sake of simplicity?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let's take a simple example as follows,

$$R=\sqrt{A^2+B^2 +2AB\cos \theta}$$

It represents the magnitude relation of vectors $\vec A$, $\vec B$, and $\vec R$ which is $\vec A +\vec B$. And we have to find $\theta$ to make the longest and shortest $R$.

We can find $\theta$ from $\frac{\textrm{d}R}{\textrm{d}\theta}=0$ as a normal method. However, I think it will be simpler if we square the $R$ first and solve $\frac{\textrm{d}R^2}{\textrm{d}\theta}=0$.

For general case, is it permissible to do such a method?

Comment: Yes. A **non-negative** quantity $Q(x)$ reaches a maximum precisely where $(Q(x))^2$ reaches a maximum. Same for minimum.

Comment: Yes, nonnegativity is definitely required.  Also remember to use the original function when obtaining the actual optimum functional value(s).

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Doc: Could  you prove it mathematically? :-)

Comment: Let $s$ and $t$ be $\ge 0$. Then $s\le t$ iff $s^2\le t^2$. If firther proof is needed, one can say that the function $x^2$ is increasing on the interval $[0,\infty)$. For this can use the derivative, or observe that $s^2\le t^2$ iff $t^2-s^2\ge 0$ iff $(s+t)(s-t)\ge 0$ iff (for $s,t\ge 0) $t\ge s$.

Comment: And not only is it permissible, it is the reasonable way to do it. Many times I have seen students get into trouble trying to differentiate $\sqrt{f(x)}$. In principle it should make no difference, in practice it is a frequent source of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $q(x)$ be a **non-negative** function of $x$. Then $q(x)$ reaches a maximum (local or global) at $x=a$ if and only if $(q(x))^2$ reaches a maximum (local or global) at $x=a$. The same is true of we replace "maximum" everywhere by "minimum."
The same is true if instead of a function $q(x)$ of one variable, we are looking at a function $q(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of several variables.

This is because of the fact that the function $f(t)=t^2$ is an increasing function on the interval $[0,\infty)$. So for any $x$ and $a$, we have $q(x)\le q(a)$ if and only if $(q(x))^2 \le (q(a))^2$.

The above remarks can be a useful simplifying device in max/min problems.

**Remark:** More generally, if $n$ is an **even** positive integer, and $q(x)$ is a non-negative function, then $q(x)$ reaches a maximum at $x=a$ if and only if $(q(x))^n$ reaches a maximum at $x=a$.

If $n$ is an **odd** positive integer, the situation is even nicer. We get that *without conditions* on $q(x)$, this reaches a maximum at $x=a$ if and only if $(q(x))^n$ does.

More generally, if $G(t)$ is an **increasing** function, then $q(x)$ reaches a maximum at $x=a$ if and only if $G(q(x))$ does.